# Variation of Coupon Collector Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I buy **7** bags of candies, each guaranteed to have one of **4** celebs' picture, with probabilities of **1/12**, **1/6**, **5/12**, and **1/3**.

What is the expected # of celebs whose picture I'll get ?

Comment: One way I know is using the multinomial distribution, but that would be very tedious. I also know how to do it with an indicator variable for a problem where each picture has equal probability of being chosen, but am unclear how to proceed here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer the question in a more general formulation:

Suppose you buy $n$ candies, each guaranteed to have one of $k$ celebs' pictures, with probabilities $p_i$ ($1\le i\le k$, and $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i = 1$).

Define the Bernoulli random variable $X_i$ to be one if you get a picture of celeb $i$ in at least one of the $n$ candies, and zero otherwise. Then it is easy to see that $$E[X_i] = \Pr[X_i=1] = 1-(1-p_i)^n$$
On the other hand, the number of celebs whose picture you get is $X_1+\cdots+X_k$.
Therefore, by the linearity of expectation, the expected number of celebs whose picture you will get is: $$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(1-(1-p_i)^n\right) = k-\sum_{i=1}^k (1-p_i)^n$$